# Can't see JSON data

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

Even though I can get a JSON file that gets downloaded, when I go to my remote URL. When I use the following code in my javascript, nothing happens:

```
<input type="text" id="query" /><button>search</button><br />
<div id="results">

</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
//var url='http://search.twitter.com/search.json?callback=?&q=google+wave';
var url = url + '/Services/GetNthClosestDriverLocationToMe?callback=?&latitude=30&longitude=-97.6&nth=2';
var query;
    $('button').click(function(){
    query=$("#query").val();
    $.getJSON(url+query,function(json){
        $.each(json.results,function(i,tweet){
           //$("#results").append('<p><img src="'+tweet.profile_image_url+'" widt="48" height="48" />'+tweet.text+'</p>');
            $("#results").append('<p>'+tweet.Name+'</p>');
        });
    });
});
});
</script>
```

Notice the commented out twitter URL that works just fine. This makes me think that it has something to do with my URL, even though I am able to get the JSON file when i simply go to the url from the browser. Also, note that my URL is on a remote domain.

Comment: is there a reason u are using jquery 1.3.2?

Comment: are getting any errors in the console ?

Comment: are you sure that you url var is ok. http : //www.domain.com  and not just www.domain.com or domain.com  . that can cause a problem.

Comment: What is $("#query").val() ? Maybe you need some ampersand there(between url and query) . You'll also need to encode it. http://api.jquery.com/serialize/ may be helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

Your `url` var is undefined in your code. This might be the problem. 
If not, please put your full code. Your url might be malformed.

Comment: The url is good. I didn't want to reveal it, but the parameters are there in case there is a problem. Plus I got it to work by simply replacing the $.each block by the following line:

     $("#results").append('<p>'+json.Name+ '</p>');

My json file looks as follows:
{
"Id":6,
"UserId":"rjones",
"Name":"Rick Jones",
"TruckType":"Van 20\u0027"
}

Comment: I still don't know why the previously stated $.each block didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the replies. After firing up fire-bug, the problem is not in the code, but in my JSON (posted in one of my replies above). Unlike the Twitter result, mine is not a collection, and thus it was erroring out on $.each.